# Table is not fitted in the device screen

Tags: jquery-mobile

I am new jquery mobile. I implemented the table.it is displaying in the browsers correctly. But it is not fitted in the device screen. How to solve this issue? please can anybody help me.

```
code
```

< html>

< head>

```
< meta charset="utf-8"> 
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"> 
<title>Single page template</title>             
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.0/jquery.mobile-1.0.min.css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.6.4.min.js"></script>       
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.0/jquery.mobile-1.0.min.js"></script>                   

<style type="text/css"> 
    table { width:100%; }       
    table th, td { text-align:left; padding:6px;}
```

< /head>

< body>

```
<div data-role="page" id="Calorie_Tracker">

   <div data-role="header" data-theme="b" >
        <a data-role="button" data-rel="back" data-icon="back">back</a>
        <h1>Calorie Tracker</h1> 
   </div>

    <div data-role="content">                           
            <table border="1" >
                <tr>
                    <th>Date</th>
                    <th>Food_Intake</th>
                    <th>Calories_Burned</th>
                    <th>Net</th>
                </tr>

                <tr>
                    <td>Dec20</td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                </tr>                       
            </table>            
    </div>

</div>
```

< /body>
< /html>

[image]

Comment: this just seems like it wont fit - column names also have no spaces - did you try reducing the font size?

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
<table data-role="table" data-mode="reflow" class="ui-responsive table-stroke"></table>
```

Comment: and don't forget to spit your table into `thead` and `tbody`, otherwise it will not work (see [API](http://api.jquerymobile.com/table/))

Answer (score 0):

(Not really an answer, but I can't post comments yet)
I am not sure if this will do for you, but you could try the JQuery Mobile Grid's:
http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0rc3/#/demos/1.0rc3/docs/content/content-grids.html

The width will adjust automatically.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old post but it looks from the screenshot that the text in the table headers mean that the minimum width is always going to be more than the screen.

You could remove the underscores between words or reduce the font-size to help the text fit but this might be of no use if the text in the data cells expands the table size again.

This is a common issue with mobile devices though - data tables don't play well with responsive designs. A good link with options / workarounds can be found here:

http://css-tricks.com/responsive-data-tables/

Hope this helps anybody with a similar issue.

Answer (score 0):

Use the CSS property `word-break: break-all`:

```
table th, td {
  text-align:left;
  padding:6px;
  word-break: break-all;
}
```